# Return only the second match for a filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that runs on two different pages. All it does is find the text of a specific div that is next to the div with the text UID. Note that I cannot edit the actual content of the page in question, otherwise I would just give these classes or IDs to target them directly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uid = $('div.label').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == 'UID';
    }).next().text();
    $('.column.right.top-ribbon-nav, .client_custom_fields_container').append(function() {
            return '<a target="_blank" class="top-nav-item pLink" style="color: red" href="https://www.xxxxxxx.com/private/index.html?content=admin2&page=userdetails&id=' + uid + '">User Page</a>';
        }
    });
    $('.pLink').on('click', function() {
        if(uid == '~') {
            alert('No UID is present for this contact. Please add it and try again.');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

This works as expected, but on one of the two pages I use it on, there are actually two matches for that variable. As a result, on that page it takes the two results and adds them together, so that the variable uid matches UID1 and UID2 and becomes UID1UID2.

In this instance, I actually only want the second match.

My thought was to add a conditional that first determines if there is more than one result for that variable. I believe I was mistaken in thinking I could do `if uid.length > 1` because uid is actually returning the text of the match for the container, not the container itself. I then tried using `index` or `eq` to get `1` which would be my second result.

I am pretty new to javascript and jquery and think I might be misunderstanding something basic that's getting in my way.

Edit: I found that I was just using `.eq()` in the wrong location. Here is my working code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var uid = $('div.label').filter(function() {
        return $(this).text() == 'UID';
    }).next().text();
    $('.column.right.top-ribbon-nav, .client_custom_fields_container').append(function() {
        if (uid.length > 1) {
            var uid2 = $('div.label').filter(function() {
                return $(this).text() == 'UID';
            }).eq(1).next().text();
            return '<a target="_blank" class="top-nav-item pLink" style="color: red" href="https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/private/index.html?content=admin2&page=userdetails&id=' + uid2 + '">User Page</a>';
        } else {
            return '<a target="_blank" class="top-nav-item pLink" style="color: red" href="https://www.xxxxxxxx.com/private/index.html?content=admin2&page=userdetails&id=' + uid + '">User Page</a>';
        }
    });
    $('.pLink').on('click', function() {
        if(uid == '~') {
            alert('No UID is present for this contact. Please add it and try again.');
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What if there are more than 2?

Comment: @Archer See my response :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result of your filter function

```
var uid = $('div.label').filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == 'UID';
});
```

And then get the last item of this result

```
var unique = uid[uid.length-1];
```

Then you can do what you want on this object

```
unique.text()...
```

Comment: I edited my original post as I found a way to use .eq() properly, but it looks like your suggestion would work in the same way, a bit more gracefully at that, so I'll mark it as my accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is the best option and is much easier to read.

You could use `.last()` or `.first()` after your initial filter to get the always the last or first one.

You could also use `.eq(1)` if it is always the second match but not the third etc.

```
var uid = $('div.label').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == 'UID';
}).last().next().text();
```

Comment: Thanks Fasani, I don't know why .last() wasn't occurring to me. In my case I'll only ever have 2 responses so that works perfectly, though I now know I can use .eq() for when I have more than 2.